# Web API Parameter Binding return instance even without request parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

With ASP.NET's WebApi, How can I assure that a complex Action parameter will always be instantiated?  Even in the absence of request parameters (in the QueryString or POST body).

For example, given this dummy action definition:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBlahBlah(GetBlahBlahInput input) { .. }
```

I want `input` to always be an instantiated instance of `GetBlahBlahInput`.  Default behavior is if request parameters exist anywhere in the request, then `input` is not null (even if none of the request parameters are bindable to `GetBlahBlahInput`.)  However, if no parameters are sent, then `GetBlahBlahInput` is `null`.  I don't want `null`, I want an instance created with the parameterless constructor.

Basically, I'm trying to implement this:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/interesting-json-model-binding

In WebApi land (so no `DefaultModelBinder` inheritance) and I want it generic, so it can handle any input type.

I'm using the default JsonMediaFormatter support in WebApi.

Any thoughts?  I'm pretty sure it can be done and I may be missing a simple configuration step somewhere.

Comment: can't you just straight forward do a 
if (input == null) input = new GetBlahBlahInput(); in the first line of the method? very simple, but maybe I am missing something

Comment: Not for what I need -- I'm writing an ActionFilterAttribute that will assign values for properties on the input model.  So this is before the Action actually fires (I'm overriding ActionExecuting()).  If I could determine the input type in the ActionFilterAttribute, I could handle it there, but it doesn't feel right.  What feels right is the ModelBinder always returning an instantiated object.

Comment: I see what you want to do now. As far as I understand WebAPI uses ModelBinder for primitive types and Formatters for complex types. I am afraid you would end up adding a lot of complexity trying to force a certain behaviour which was not intended. I would rather use the standard way and accept that input may be null if its not provided. Sorry, that I can't help.

Comment: Are you using attribute routing as there is a known issue with this and attribute routing?

Comment: I am using attribute routing, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still wondering if what I asked about can be done.  But for the time being, here's the workaround I implemented in my ActionFilterAttribute (`inputKey` is the name of the parameter; in the original question it's `input`):

```
// look for the "input" parameter and try to instantiate it and see if it implements the interface I'm interested in
var parameterDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.ParameterName, inputKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);
if (parameterDescriptor == null 
    || (inputArgument = Activator.CreateInstance(parameterDescriptor.ParameterType) as IHasBlahBlahId) == null)
{
    // if missing "input" parameter descriptor or it isn't an IHasBlahBlahId, then return unauthorized
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    return;
}

// otherwise, take that newly instantiated object and throw it into the ActionArguments!
if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(inputKey))
    actionContext.ActionArguments[inputKey] = inputArgument;
else
    actionContext.ActionArguments.Add(inputKey, inputArgument);
```

Comment: Did you find another way to do this?

Comment: Nope, I never did.  But I haven't been coding with WebApi for almost a year and a half now, so I've lost touch on the latest and greatest.

Comment: Fair enough mate, but after a year and an half the latest and greatest is still broken :P