# How to make sure that a action class parameter is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Given the code bellow:

```
public CollectionResult<SetupsDetailsModels> GetSetupsDetails([FromUri]SetupsDetailsCollectionFilterMapping filter)
```

If the request does not contain any query parameters the filter object is always null, how to make sure that even if no parameters are sent that an instance is always created?

An easy way is to add a Message Handler and add a dummy query string parameter that way the object is always created, but I really don't like this solution.

Thanks

Comment: how about `if(filter == null) filter = new SetupsDetailsCollectionFilterMapping();` at the beginning of your method?

Comment: Yes I can do that, but given that I have quite a few routes with the same args, I don't like having to repeat that all over the place. On a side note, I might be able to use just a ActionFilter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765087/web-api-parameter-binding-return-instance-even-without-request-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fallowing the idea I found here [Web API Parameter Binding return instance even without request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765087/web-api-parameter-binding-return-instance-even-without-request-parameters)

This is what I will do:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var parameterDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters().FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(CollectionFilterMapping).IsAssignableFrom(x.ParameterType));

    if (parameterDescriptor != null && actionContext.ActionArguments[parameterDescriptor.ParameterName] == null)
    {
        actionContext.ActionArguments[parameterDescriptor.ParameterName] = Activator.CreateInstance(parameterDescriptor.ParameterType);
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even using an action filter you would still have to add it to all methods you needed it on. Alternatively you could just use a default parameter.

```
public CollectionResult<SetupsDetailsModels> GetSetupsDetails([FromUri]SetupsDetailsCollectionFilterMapping filter = new SetupsDetailsCollectionFilterMapping())
```

Comment: Yes I could to that, and at least is better than having to do the check in Evey other route, but I will go the ActionFilter route. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could set it in your defaults for your route:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "test",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{filter}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", filter = new SetupsDetailsCollectionFilterMapping() }
            );
```

If the `filter` is null it will create a new instance of `SetupsDetailsCollectionFilterMapping`, otherwise it will be the `filter` that you've passed through.

Would save you having to go through all of your methods and adding action filters.

Just tested it out with something similar and it works.

Comment: I have no routes defined that way, everything is defined with Action attributes. Thanks